# Удалить картинку с сайта при нажатии на нее ajax

Tags: php, ajax

При нажатии на картинку нужно чтобы она удалились. Прикрепляю код ниже. Подскажите где ошибка. При нажатии на картинку у меня виснет страница, через дебаггер не посмотреть все виснет намертво.

```
$mnogo = "SELECT * FROM images where tovars_id=$_REQUEST[id]";  
$rows=$dbh->query($mnogo)->fetchAll();
<? foreach($rows as $k=>$img){ ?>
<img id="output_<?=$k?>" data-id="<?=$img[id]?>" class="modal_images" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" src="<?= $img['name'] ?>">
<?}?>

<?

if ($_POST[upload]) {
    $id = $_POST[id];
    $uploaddir = '/i/';
    file_put_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/_.txt", "\n\r".__FILE__.":".__LINE__."\n\r".print_r($_FILES, true));
    foreach($_FILES['userfile']['name']as $m = > $w) {
        if (($_FILES['userfile']['type'][$m] == 'image/gif' || $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$m] == 'image/jpeg' || $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$m] == 'image/png') && ($_FILES['userfile']['size'][$m] != 0
        and $_FILES[ 'userfile']['size'][$m]<=1024000))
        {
            $ex = explode('.', $w);
            $ex = end($ex);
            $apend = date('YmdHis').rand(100, 1000). '.'.$ex;
            $uploadfile = "$uploaddir$apend";

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$m], $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT].$uploadfile)) {
                $c = "INSERT INTO images (name, tovars_id) VALUES('$uploadfile', '$id')";
                $query = $dbh -> prepare($c);
                $query -> execute();
            }
        }
    }
    header("Location: /pr1.php");
    exit;
} elseif($_POST[image_delete]) {
    $id = $_POST[image_id];
    $src = $_POST[src];
    $c = "DELETE FROM `images` WHERE id=$id";
    //unlink($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT].$src); 

    $query1 = $dbh -> prepare($c);
    $query1 -> execute();
} else {
    echo "Error2";
}

?>

$(".modal_images").click(function() {
    id = this.dataset.id;
    src = this.attributes.src;
    //$.ajax("/exit.php", {image_id:id, src: src, image_delete: 'true'}/*, function (){$(this).fadeOut("slow")}*/);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"exit.php",
        data:{
            image_id:
            id, src:src, image_delete:'true'
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Много ли строк в таблице `images`?

Comment: 3 поля (id. name. tovars_id) Строк много

Comment: поменял на $id виснет по прежнему

Comment: По-моему, в таком коде вам проще самому найти ошибку....закоментируйте бОльшую часть кода, перезагрузите страницу....если "отпустила" раскомментируйте постепенно, пока не наткнетесь на то, что будет пускать страницу в зависоны.......попробуйте запрос в обычной программе.... сколько строк выдаст...не много ли...не зависнет ли программа уже на запросе `Select`........... а то вы сейчас пытаетесь возвать  к сеансу телепатической отладки ....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, комментировал ajax запрос, зависаний нет как и удаления картинки.Из базы выводится всего 4 картинки так что тут ни чего перегруженного нету.

Answer (score 1):

Используй стандартный POST запрос:

```
$('#image').click(function (e) {
    var image = $(this).attr("src");
    var delete_var = 'act=delete_image&image=' + image + '';
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"ajax.php",
        data:delete_var,
        success:function(data) {
            alert('deleted');
        }
    });
});
```

ajax.php

```
if ($_POST['act'] == 'delete_image') {
    $image = $_POST['image']; // название файла (src)
    // тут код удаления файла
}
```

Поправьте меня, не знаю, правильно ли я получил название картинки через Jquery. В целом, решение должно быть правильным.